# Unable to redirect in react js via redirect command

Tags: reactjs

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery'; 
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch,Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';

// Getting the country code from the user's IP

// List of countries we want to block
// To see this in action add your country code to the array
var blacklist = ['US', 'CA', 'UK','IN']

// Getting the country code from the user's IP
$.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=97173fac13f575130327fc00f93b12fe62ea33afb45930438111a4ea", function (response) {

  // Checking if the user's country code is in the blacklist
  // You could inverse the logic here to use a whitelist instead
  if (blacklist.includes(response.country_code)) {
    <Redirect push to="/home" />


    alert('This content is not available at your location.');
  

  

    
    
  } else {
    alert("You're allowed to see this!")
  }
}, "jsonp");






function App() {
  return (
    <>
   
      <Router>
           
           <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
             <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
             <Redirect to="/"/>
             
            </Switch>
         </Router>
    </>
  
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am blocking the users from specific country using api of ipdata,I want that it should redirect me after showing the alert that this content is not avalible, but I am not getting redirected after I see the alert.When I use windows.location command that its redirecting me again and again very quickly.

Comment: please answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery'; 
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch,Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';

// Getting the country code from the user's IP

// List of countries we want to block
// To see this in action add your country code to the array
var blacklist = ['US', 'CA', 'UK','IN']

// Getting the country code from the user's IP
$.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=97173fac13f575130327fc00f93b12fe62ea33afb45930438111a4ea", function (response) {

  // Checking if the user's country code is in the blacklist
  // You could inverse the logic here to use a whitelist instead
  if (blacklist.includes(response.country_code)) {
     if ( window.location!= "http://localhost:3000/home"){  
          window.location = "http://localhost:3000/home"}
     else{
        console.log("sorry")
     }
    alert('This content is not available at your location.');
  

  

    
    
  } else {
    alert("You're allowed to see this!")
  }
}, "jsonp");
```

basicly I just added a if condition you can check that out and now its working perfectly!!